# javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <file_name>(Access is denied)

Tags: java, parsing, dom, file-io, xerces

I am getting exception at last line of code -

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
DOMSource xmlSource = new DOMSource(document);

StreamResult result;
File f = new File(sFilePath);
if (f.exists() == false) {
   result = new StreamResult(f);
} else {
   result = new StreamResult(sFilePath);
}

transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

The exception stacktrace is -

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\ProgramData.\config\.xml (Access is
>   denied) stacktrace javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\ProgramData.\config\.xml (Access is
>   denied) at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown
>   Source) at com..main.dr.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.dr.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.dr.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.h.k(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.ay.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\ProgramData.\config\.xml (Access is
>   denied) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream. (Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream. (Unknown Source) ... 7 more ---------
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\ProgramData.\config\.xml (Access is
>   denied) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream. (Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream. (Unknown Source) at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown
>   Source) at com..main.dr.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.dr.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.dr.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.h.k(Unknown Source) at
>   com..main.ay.run(Unknown Source) and the cause
>   isjava.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\ProgramData.\config\.xml (Access is
>   denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like file permissions on your XML files, doesn't it?

If you're executing from a web context, please bear in mind that the web user (for example, "nobody" under Linux/Apache, or "IUSR_MACHINE" under Windows/IIS) has MINIMAL privileges to access your filesystem.

And this is a Good Thing: especially if your application is exposed to the Internet :)

PS:
Also, the directory path you cited doesn't look right:

> C:\ProgramData.\config.xml

Are you sure it's not supposed to be "C:\Program Data\config.xml"????

PPS:
While we're talking about "file permissions"; Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Server 2008 all have stricter rules against accessing anything in a drive's root (EX: "c:\") or system directories (EX: "c:\windows" or "c:\Program files").

Comment: My application is java desktop application. This application automatically run first time. Whenever user going to run it next time, it throws Access is denied as program can not able to access configuration files at C:\ProgramData.

Comment: So are you saying 1) it always runs successfully the first time, but 2) it always fails the 2nd and subsequent times?  That sounds like "file in use" error.  Perhaps you're not closing all your files (in a "finally")?  ALSO: look here: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html: "Why do I get 'fle not found'?"

Comment: The issue is related file permission in "C:\Program Data\.."

Answer (score 10):

Try changing it to use the file's `URI.getPath()` instead of just passing File object into StreamResult.

eg. `StreamResult result = new StreamResult(anOutputFile.toURI().getPath());`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether the file you try to transform does have the values and that they are valid.

May be you are iterating over a set of files using a loop and some times you end up trying to transform files which do not have any value like `null` or  `""`.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/YOURFILEADDRESS.xml");
```