# Getting FileNotFoundException (Permission Denied) on saving xml file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save an xml file to a USB device connected to an android device via USB OTG, and I'm getting this exception:

```
javax.xml transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/usb/filename.xml (Permission denied)
```

`/mnt/usb` is the path to the USB device.

If I change the path to something local on the device, everything works.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675292/javax-xml-transform-transformerexception-java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-n) and tried changing this line:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File( PATH, filename ));
```

to:

```
File myfile = new File( PATH, filename );
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(myfile.toURI().getPath());
```

But the same exception occurred.

On the USB device itself, I can't find any permission configurations, but I can create files in it when connected to PC.

Comment: Have you tried with `file.setWritable(true)`?

Comment: have you included WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: @bigdestroyer - Didn't work... Same thing

Comment: Are you sure that your USB is mounted in /mnt/usb?

Comment: @bigdestroyer Hmm... That might be the problem

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609114/how-to-read-write-external-usb-storage-on-android